# Show Output of Controller method via Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I just started working on Thymeleaf and wanted to connect a Spring Boot application with HTML using Thymeleaf. I had my "normal" controllers without Thymeleaf like this:

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/{id}")
    public BookEntity getBookById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return bookService.getById(id);
    }



@GetMapping
        public List<BookEntity> getAllBooks() {
            return bookService.findAll();
        }
```

Now that Im using Thymeleaf I created some new Controllers like this:

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/book/{id}")
    public String getBookById(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        BookEntity book= bookService.getById(id);
        model.addAttribute("book", book);
        return "book/{id}";
    }
    
@GetMapping("/book/all")
    public String AllBooks(Model model) {
        List<BookEntity> books = bookService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("books", books);

        return "books";
    }
```

I also created a book.html file in resources/templates like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Books</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Select action to do something</h4>
<form th:action="@{/book/{id}(id=book.getId())" method="get">
    <label for="id">id:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="id" name="id" placeholder="id" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

But this isnt working I wanted to submit the book Id (in the input) and in return I get the Book with the right id. I tried to use ModelAndView instead of Model and return a ModelAndView but it didnt work. Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The String return type you use in a `@Controller` (as opposed to the `@RestController` you used before) indicates the name of the Thymeleaf template.

Normally, I would use 2 templates:

- `book-list.html` to show the list of books
- `book.html` to show the details of a single book

Those files need to be in `src/main/resources/templates`. Assuming you have that, your controller becomes:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/books/{id}")
    public String getBookById(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        BookEntity book = bookService.getById(id);
        model.addAttribute("book", book);
        return "book";
    }
    
@GetMapping("/books")
    public String AllBooks(Model model) {
        List<BookEntity> books = bookService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("books", books);

        return "book-list";
    }
```

In `book-list.html`, you can do something like this:

```
<tr th:each="book: ${books}">
    <td th:text="${book.id}" />
    <td th:text="${book.name}" />
    <td><a th:href="@{/books/{id}(id=book.id)">View details</a></td>
</tr>
```

In `book.html`, you can show the details of the book:

```
<div>
  <h1 th:text="${book.name}"></h1>
  ...
</div>
```

Now opening your browser to http://localhost:8080/books should show the list of books with hyperlinks to navigate to the details of the book.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to understand without extracting `books` how can you get book id. You have to extract books and put `book_id` in anchor tag link href. If you click on the link tag, you find that perticular book data.

Here down is code.

Suppose `Entity` is:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer page;
    
    // getter setter
}
```

**Contorller**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/books/{id}")
public String getBookById(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
    BookEntity book = bookService.getById(id);
    model.addAttribute("book", book);
    return "book";
}
    
@GetMapping("/books")
public String AllBooks(Model model) {
   List<BookEntity> books = bookService.findAll();
   model.addAttribute("books", books);
   return "books";
}
```

Here down is two templates `book.html` and `books.html`. Path of this both file is `src/main/resources/templates`.

**books.html**

```
<tr th:each="book: ${books}">
    <td th:text="${book.id}" />
    <td th:text="${book.name}" />
    <td th:text="${book.page}" />
    <td><a th:href="@{/books/{id}(id=book.id)">Go To Book</a></td>
</tr>
```

**book.html**

```
<div>
  Book Name: <label th:text="${book.name}"></label>
  How Many Pages: <label th:text="${book.page}"></label>
</div>
```